# RewriteEngine not working on subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)tiny_mce_popup\.js$ /d_text.cgi?act=tiny_mce_popup.js [L]
RewriteRule (.*)sitemap\.xml$ /d_text.cgi?act=sitemap.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cgi?act=select&htmlfile=$1 [QSA]
```

Now this is working fine on main domains (like example.com, other.com etc.), but not working on subdomains (like sub.example.com, mysubdomain.other.com, etc.). What is the problem here?

Comment: Your subdomains have the same document root as your main domain?

Comment: The main domain is here: /var/www/mydomain.com  and the subdomain is here: /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com